# How to sort an array of objects by a property of each object

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of data returned from the eventbrite.com api stored in a variable called $restrictedEvents which looks like the data below. This is representative of just one event for the purposes of pasting here but it has a about 80 stdClass Objects like this in the full array.

I want to sort this array alphabetically by the [title] key in each stdClass Object. I have tried using:

```
usort($restrictedEvents, "title");
```

However this returns the following error:

```
Warning: usort() [function.usort]: Invalid comparison function in model.php on line 109
```

My guess is it cannot find the title key as this is in the next level down. Any pointers on where I am going wrong and how I can sort by the title would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

```
Array 
(
[4791063199] => stdClass Object
    (
        [box_header_text_color] => 393837
        [link_color] => EE6600
        [box_background_color] => FFFFFF
        [box_border_color] => D9D4D0
        [timezone] => Europe/London
        [organizer] => stdClass Object
            (
                [url] => http://www.eventbrite.com/org/2866607767
                [description] => 
                [long_description] => 
                [id] => 2866607767
                [name] => B&Q Manifestival
            )

        [background_color] => E3DFDC
        [id] => 4791063199
        [category] => 
        [box_header_background_color] => F0ECE9
        [capacity] => 20
        [num_attendee_rows] => 0
        [title] => Closed Event Test
        [start_date] => 2012-11-07 19:00:00
        [status] => Live
        [description] => Lorem ipsum
        [end_date] => 2012-11-07 21:00:00
        [tags] => 
        [timezone_offset] => GMT+0000
        [text_color] => 393837
        [title_text_color] => 
        [password] => 
        [tickets] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ticket] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [description] => 
                                [end_date] => 2012-11-07 17:00:00
                                [min] => 1
                                [max] => 1
                                [price] => 0.00
                                [quantity_sold] => 0
                                [visible] => true
                                [currency] => GBP
                                [quantity_available] => 20
                                [type] => 0
                                [id] => 15940001
                                [name] => Manifestival Event
                            )

                    )

            )

        [created] => 2012-11-07 10:40:36
        [url] => http://www.eventbrite.com/event/4791063199
        [box_text_color] => 393837
        [privacy] => Private
        [venue] => stdClass Object
            (
                [city] => 
                [name] => HR Training Room
                [country] => 
                [region] => 
                [longitude] => 0
                [postal_code] => 
                [address_2] => 
                [address] => 
                [latitude] => 0
                [country_code] => 
                [id] => 2619469
                [Lat-Long] => 0.0 / 0.0
            )

        [modified] => 2012-11-07 10:47:20
        [repeats] => no
    )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second paramater to `usort` should be a function. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php. You would need to pass it a function like:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->title, $b->title);
}
```

I think you would then call it like `usort($restrictedEvents, "cmp");`.

Comment: Since he's dealing with an stdclass and not an array, it would need to be `return strcmp($a->title, $b->title);`, but apart from that it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies):

```
$result = Arrays::sort($restrictedEvents, Comparator::compareBy('title'));
```

http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/comparators.html

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to `usort` is a function, not a key name.  The function gets passed two elements of the array being sorted and returns a value indicating how those two elements should be ordered with respect to each other: -1 if the order in which they're passed to the function is correct, 1 if it's reversed, and 0 if it doesn't matter (the two elements are equal as far as the comparison goes). Here's an example for your case:

```
usort($restrictedEvents, 
      function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a->title, $b->title); });
```

If you're on an older PHP (before 5.3.0, which introduced anonymous functions), then you have to give the comparison function a name and pass that name as a string to `usort`:

```
function titlecmp($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a->title, $b->title); 
}
usort($restrictedEvents, "titlecmp");
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually something like this is achieved via a second array with `$keyToSort => $id`, sort this array via the standart sort functions or your own, then you have a conversion to your first array

using this, the depth of your array is limitless.